# How to get my X_rotated with Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: image, rotation, keras

Hi I just want my databasis of MNIST randomly rotated:

I have my X which is a numpy array (5000, 1, 28, 28)
I want the X_rotated in the same order same dimension.

I have made this:

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=360)

datagen.fit(X)

Now how I get my X_rotated ?

They only explain how to make tricky stuff with epoch and batch I just want to get back my array where each image has randomly rotated nothing more, nothing tricky.
I don't understand why on tutorials they only explain how to make the tricky stuff but not the basics...

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Answer (score 0):

The `NumpyArrayIterador` and `DirectoryIterator` objects are pretty much like any python iterator:

```py
g = ImageDataGenerator(...)
d = g.flow(..., batch_size=256, shuffle=False)

# flow all batches through the iterator,
# then zip all inputs and outputs, respectively.
batches = zip(*(next(d) for _ in range(len(d))))

# concatenate all inputs and outputs, respectively.
x, y = (np.concatenate(b) for b in batches)

print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

This should output something similar to this:

> (5000, 1, 28, 28) (5000, ?)

Comment: But I just want to get my X_rotated I don't want to display anything.

Comment: And this will shuffle my array I don't want that the order is really important I want exactly the same array same order.

Comment: I reflected the answer to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help !